# Deserialize JSON Data automatically when using timestamp

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json.net

I need to bring javascript timestamp to server in datetime format. My javascript object contains a property with datetimstamp
`ex : {"fromDate" : "new Date(1427826600000)"}`

But the model on the server side has `fromDate` as `DateTime`. I need to deserialize it to DateTime on server side as I'm using different cultures.

below is the code.

**Ajax Call**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Report/Update",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify(model),
```

**Model**

```
public class Report
{
 [JsonConverter(typeof (JavaScriptDateTimeConverter))]
 public DateTime FromDate { get; set; }

 [JsonConverter(typeof (JavaScriptDateTimeConverter))]
 public DateTime ToDate { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult UpdateReport(Report data)
{
        ...
}
```

I'm unable to do this can you help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Provided that `aMs` contains JS date, use this code to convert it to C# DateTime:

```
new DateTime(aMs * 10000 + 621355968000000000L);
```

Comment: To do this way we need to add a new int property. I'm trying to avoid that. And can't we achieve this using jsonserializer?

Comment: Actually you already have JavaScriptDateTimeConverter attached to your properties, it should perform the conversion automatically without any further processing. Why doesn't it work for you?

Comment: Also in your code, ex : {"fromDate" : "new Date(1427826600000)"} - shouldn't it be : {"fromDate" : 1427826600000}

Comment: As I'm using ajax to call the method, data isn't getting deserialised automatically

Comment: However you want it I can do that. But it has to be timestamp in order to support localization

Comment: If you are sending {"fromDate" : "new Date(1427826600000)"} to the server, the "new Date(1427826600000)" will never be converted, because you are sending not a date, but a Javascript command to create new date, and your C# server does not understand Javascript commands. Try sending  {"fromDate" : X}, where X is the number that you pass to new Date()

Comment: I tried in the way you said but its still not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79970/discussion-between-krishna-thota-and-denis-yarkovoy).